# How can I output a length of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, output

I'm trying to find a way to output an array in alphabetical order as well as the length by a window alert, or alternatively any way for the user to be able to see it, when they're in the browser.

Here is the little bit of code:-

```
var vehicles = ["Car", "Bus", "Train", "Boat","Plane"];
vehicles.sort();
```

As well as:-

```
vehicles.length();
```

Comment: `length` is property not `method`.... For `Array#sort`, refer [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: If you need an official source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: @PranavCBalan Ah, thanks. I will amend that in my code.

Comment: What did not work with `vehicles.sort();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `vehicles.length` not `vehicles.length()`

You can output in an alert

```
alert( vehicles.length );
```

or log into the console

```
console.log( vehicles.length );
```